# Как исправить? invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо написать все возможные подмножества множества. Все хорошо, однако вывод просят в int, а у меня получается массивы строк. При попытки перекроить их в int выскакивает эта ошибка
Вот код:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
n = len(nums)
mas_st = ['0'*n]*2**n
for i in range(2**n):
    mas_st[i] += str(bin(i))[2:]
    mas_st[i] = mas_st[i][-n:]
ans_list = [0]*2**n
for i in range(2**n):
    temp = [0]*n
    for j in range(n):
        temp[j]=((str(nums[j])*int(mas_st[i][j])))
    print(temp)
    ans_list[i] = [int(q[1:-1]) for q in temp]
```

Comment: Какой ожидается ответ для  множества `[1, 2, 3]`?